# Exponentials don't cancel numerically

Tags: numerics, symbolic

I'm trying something essentially like

```
N[Exp[-x]*(D[Exp[x*y^2], y] /. y -> 1)]
```

After differentiation and `y -> 1` there is an `Exp[x]` factor that should cancel the `Exp[-x]`, but *Mathematica* returns something like

> `2.71828^x (something*2.71828^(-1. x))`

How do I tell *Mathematica* that `-1. x` is actually `x` so that it can cancel the two exponentials?

Comment: This looks interesting ... Do you have a space between "x" and "y^2"?  Perhaps see what happens first without applying `N[]`.  Could you please post the code "as code" in a gray box?  It may be easier for others to see exactly what is happening.  Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window. The edit window help button `?` is useful for learning how to format your questions and answers. You may also find [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `FullSimplify`

```
N[Exp[-x] (D[Exp[x*y]*y^(1/2), y] /. y -> 1)] // FullSimplify
```

> 0.5 + 1. x

Answer (score 2):

Some further remarks.

In the case of the example code `FullSimplify` is overkill; `Simplify` will do.

```
N[Exp[-x] (D[Exp[x y^2], y] /. y -> 1)] // Simplify
```

> `2. x`

Even `Simplify` can be avoided if the replacement is done before the numeric evaluation.

```
N[Exp[-x] D[Exp[x y^2], y] /. y -> 1]
```

> `2. x`

Answer (score 0):

Just so you know Mathematica does not treat `xy` as x *times* y, but rather as a new variable called `xy`. So adding an explicit `*` character will show that you actually want them multiplied. Adding just the space gives me the following, which seems fair enough:

```
In[5]:= N[Exp[-x] (D[Exp[x * y^2], y] /. y -> 1)]
```

Which yields

```
Out[5]= 2. x
```

Does this solve your issue?

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but I was aware of 'multiplying' x and y.

Comment: I see this example is working. I simplified the problem a bit too much. Please take a look at N[Exp[-x] (D[Exp[x*y]*y^(1/2), y] /. y -> 1)]

Comment: which gives 2.71828^(-1. x) (0.5 2.71828^x + 2.71828^x x)

Comment: I think the problem arises when there are fractional exponents

Comment: @zhk that works perfectly! Thanks